# Why do Floating <a> tag cause <li> to Float in CSS?

Tags: html, css

As we know one way to making horizontal menu is to floating list items left.
but in most cases I saw, they making horizontal menu with CSS by using float property inside of `<a>` tags that are inside `<li>` tag.
but why do float property of `<a>` tag cause its parent tag `<li>` floated to left? what's the difference between using float property inside `<li>` and `<a>` tag? why don't we use float:left inside `<li>` to make horizontal menu?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but why do float property of `<a>` tag cause its parent tag `<li>` floated to left?

It doesn't.

Floating the `a` element takes it out of normal flow.

The `li` element therefore has no content in normal flow.

The default height, which hasn't been overridden, of the `li` element is `auto` which gets computed as `0`.

This allows the following content to move up beside it.

---

> why don't we use float:left inside `<li>` to make horizontal menu?

Today we generally don't, but when we did then floating the list item was the usual approach taken.

`float` is designed to let content flow around images (etc) to create effects like this example from the CSS specification:

[image: example of floats]

Decades ago CSS lacked real layout tools and `float` was used as a hack.

Today we have Flexbox and Grid which are designed for this type of layout.